# Custom back button in Navigation Bar Controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, ios7, uinavigationitem

I customize de back button of navigation controller for make a concret action when push it. 
I do these:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                             initWithTitle:@"Atrás"
                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                             target:self
                                             action:@selector(pop)];
```

Now, I need to put the same back arrow in my custom button because the rest of buttons are default back button. Exists any way to do these without images?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a UINavigationController, and push all of your views thru it, you will get the default iOS back button styles.  If you're just using a UINavigationBar that you add to your Views yourself, then it's up to you to create the style of that button.  To match what you get with a UINavigationController, you may have to resort to images.

Comment: I'm using a NAvigation Controller insida a Storyboard.               How I can get, as you say, the default style?

Comment: If you're using a UINavigationController, your back buttons should get the default look and feel.  If you're creating a custom button to replace the back button, you're on your own.

Comment: Ok, the reason why I'm customizing my Back button it's because I need to run a concrete action when the button is pressed. I discovered another method to do these, I put into ViewWillDesapear what method I want to run and a condiction for the exception when I go to the next view these method don't run. Thank's!